# Is my Nest thermostat wired correctly?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, nest

I've been having issues like the heat pump not heating.  Now that it's hot outside, my A/C isn't working. Can someone tell me if my Nest thermostat is even wired correctly?

[image: Thermostat]

[image: Heatpump]

[image: Heatpump2]

**If it helps any, here is how the original one was wired and it worked just fine.**

[image: Original]

Comment: Those are the outside heat pump connections, the thermostat will be connected to a control module, usually on or next to the indoor vent/heat unit.

Comment: @Stavr00 I have a crawl space so I got under the house and looked at the furnace but didn't find any wires.  I also traced the wires running from the outside unit, into the house, and they don't appear to be running with the other piping.  I don't know if they go up the walls?  I guess I don't know what I'm looking for.  There are two panels on my furnace, the switches/breakers, and the filter access panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are things to check first:
- Check the 220V breaker serving the heat pump.
- Check the over-pressure valve breaker on the heat pump.

Comment: No breakers seem to be thrown.  When I turn the A/C on, it does blow air out.  It's just not cold.  My heat works too, or at least my AUX heat does.  Heat pump is questionable in performance.  Also, I don't know where the pressure valve breaker is at.  I looked at the switches on the furnace under the house, they're both ON.  There's a box attached to the side of my house, which has a big wire loom running into the outside unit.  It just has a black pull-type lever in it.  Not sure if that's what I'm looking for.  Or, is the pressure breaker inside the outdoor unit?

Comment: You can try to jump  `R` to `Y` on the heat pump unit to see if it'll turn on (careful not to get sliced by the fan blade!)  Leave it on for a few seconds. but don't do it repeatedly or you risk burning out the compressor.